# Is it possible to change Foliate's TTS client?

Tags: text-to-speech, ebooks, foliate

I am not a fan of reading books from a computer screen.

I install `Foliate` to listen to my epub books while I am working on the PC. It uses `festival tts` by default.

I have `Glate` on Ubuntu 20.04. And they say that `Glate` has `Google TTS` included. Can I and how can I use `Google TTS` on `Foliate` instead of `festival tts`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ask the developer. https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues

Comment: Thanks. Now I've sent my question to the developer.

Comment: I could not determine how to install glate from source. I have asked its developer here https://github.com/keshavbhatt/glate/issues/9 . Unless glate has a command line interface (does it?) Foliate cannot use it, AFAIK.

Comment: Now that we have the developer's answer in GitHub, (I have verified that it works),  feel free to post the instructions as an answer here (or let me know if you don't want to post the answer yourself). It may help someone else in future.